# Problema na paginação

Tags: php, paginação

Estou fazendo uma paginação. Até aí tudo bem, mas quando eu estou na página inicial, ela mostra os resultados, tudo ok. Mas, quando eu clico para ir para a página `2`, ele só muda o último resultado da página.

exemplo produtos.php

id `45,46,47,48,49` nessa página está tudo ok. Mas, na página `produtos.php?pagina=1`, mostra assim `46,47,48,49,50`.

```
    session_start();
    require '../conectaBanco.php';
    $itens_pagina = 5;
    if (isset($_GET['pagina'])) {
    $pagina = $_GET['pagina'];
    } else {
    $pagina = 0;
    }
    $sql_code = "SELECT * FROM produtos LIMIT $pagina, $itens_pagina";
    $execute = $conecta->query($sql_code) or die($$conecta->error);
    $produto = $execute->fetch_assoc();
    $num = $execute->num_rows;
    $num_total = $conecta->query("SELECT * FROM produtos")->num_rows;
    $num_paginas = ceil($num_total / $itens_pagina);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
session_start();
require '../conectaBanco.php';
$itens_pagina = 5;
if (isset($_GET['pagina']))
    $pagina = $_GET['pagina'] * $itens_pagina ; // mudei aqui
else
    $pagina = 0;

$sql_code = "SELECT * FROM produtos LIMIT $pagina, $itens_pagina";
$execute = $conecta->query($sql_code) or die($$conecta->error);
$produto = $execute->fetch_assoc();
$num = $execute->num_rows;
$num_total = $conecta->query("SELECT * FROM produtos")->num_rows;
$num_paginas = ceil($num_total / $itens_pagina);
```

Quando houver uma página na URL, você deve multiplicar esse número pela quantidade de itens que você quer nessa página, por exemplo:

- Página 1 -> `$pagina` = 1 * 5 = 05, então lista de 05, a 10
- Página 2 -> `$pagina` = 2 * 5 = 10, então lista de 10, a 15
- Página 3 -> `$pagina` = 3 * 5 = 15, então lista de 15, a 20

Comment: blz deu certo :D

Comment: Adicionei a explicação, para você entender :)